# Function registered by XtAppAddWorkProc is called many times

Tags: c, background-process, exceed

I've register a function to work on background by below code:

```
XtAppAddWorkProc(app, (XtWorkProc)NotifyEntryCallback, (XtPointer)ent);
```

It wil be ok if I just call this function once in a task (click on a button for example). 
But when I call it twice or more in that task, `NotifyEntryCallback` will be called many time (infinity).

I try to store `XtAppAddWorkProc` use `XtRemoveWorkProc` function to remove the registered function but it still does not work.

I has spent many times on Google but cannot know why this happens. Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution. I share it for anyone faces the same issue:

The return value in `XtWorkProc` tell system call registered function again or not. In this case, `NotifyEntryCallback` should `return True` if I don't want it to be called again.

Reference link:
http://home.soka.ac.jp/~unemi/Motif/man3/XtWorkProc.html